# How can I print one layer of a Minecraft schematic on paper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have exported some of my world into a schematic by MCEdit.

And now I want to print the first layer of my schematic onto paper (since I don't have a 3D printer, I should print it layer by layer)

What should I do?

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by "first layer" and maybe describe what you need this printed for? Some screenshots might help also.

Comment: I mean the ground layer. the structure is a court and I need the base layer as a map.

Comment: Do you want just a flat layer or a Papercraft-style thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about printing files.

Comment: @Frank About printing files of a game called Mine Craft. Not every printing file! plus, This problem may happen to any MC player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshots, I'd say Schematic2Blueprint may be able to do it depending on the blocks involved. Someone aside from the original creator updated it with a lot of newer blocks, too.

Original: http://klaue.net16.net/programme/ownprogs/java/schematic2blueprint.en.php

Updated: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cpgmka6mmqgjan/Schematic2Blueprint.jar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Update the schematic2blueprint project seems to have been taken over by Inostupid Streams...
http://double-helix.industries/applications/schematic2blueprint/#download

It seems to understand purpur blocks and end bricks, but not end rods, or dragon heads.

You can see me preparing and building a statue using it in my video
Ant 024 Survival Statue

Comment: You should summarize the video in case the video ever dies.

Comment: Summery...  I use a minecraft client with forge and world edit, explaining world edit does not appear to need match the specific version of MC.  Load a schematic I found.  Remove the excess of gold blocks, and hollow it out, to reduce resources needed.  Then save the schemematic.  I show using schematic2blueprint to compare materials used (before and after).  I think go to a survival world using resources form a skulker box, I build the statue, showing the s2b window, and show how I keep layers aligned, and how I do block placing for each level.  Video is better.